# Remove indent from the first line of multicol text included with \input in memoir

Tags: memoir, indentation, input

How can the first line indent be removed from the text, included with `\input` macro in a `\multicol` environment?

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,12pt,english]{memoir}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{multicol} 
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}

\begin{document}
\begin{multicols}{5}
    \begingroup
    \obeylines
    \input{test.txt}
    \endgroup
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

The `test.txt` contents can be found here: http://pastebin.com/raw/a344UbuH

Every line of included text starts with indent:
[image]

I can remove the indent if `multicol` environment is not used by adding `\noindent`, but it does not work in `multicol`.

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,12pt,english]{memoir}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}

\begin{document}
%    \noindent
    \input{test.txt}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Putting `\parindent=0pt` into either your preamble or inside the `multicols` environment will fix the indentation issue but, for reasons that I don't understand, the `multicols` environment is not respecting the `\obeylines` command.

Comment: Ah, I see I was being stupid and not realizing that `multicols` put your input into 5 columns. As egreg also noted, `\parindent=0pt` is what you needed.

Comment: Not stupid at all if you ask me!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do `\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}` at the appropriate spot, which is after `\begin{multicols}{5}`. This setting will apply only up to `\end{multicols}`.

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,12pt,english]{memoir}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{multicol} 
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}

\begin{document}
\begin{multicols}{5}
  \setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
  \begingroup
  \obeylines
  \input{test.txt}
  \endgroup
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is perfect that the effect is local to the environment as everywhere else the first line indent is required!

Answer (score 2):

The indentation of the included file will be the same as the indentation in the rest of your document. If you want no indentation then you can add the line `\parindent=0pt` to your document.

Having said this, I don't see any indentation in your MWE. Adding `\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}` to your MWE and also including some extra lines outside of the `\input{file.txt}` this is what I get:

[image]

This shows that the text is flush with the lefthand margin. That is, there is no indentation.

Here's my MWE:

```
\documentclass[10pt,letterpaper]{letter}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}

\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\begin{document}
    \begin{letter}

\input{file.txt}

abc

def

ghi

    \end{letter}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Edited MWE to demonstrate my issue. It is `memoir` that makes a difference, `letter` is fine indeed.